# Path problem in automatically produced .tex-file using gnuplot with terminal cairolatex

Tags: graphics, gnuplot, directory

I'm using the `terminal cairolatex` in a gnuplot script. This produces a    .tex    -file and a    .pdf   -file with the same name specified in    `set output`    .The problem is, that both files are in subdirectories, so I have to write something like    `\input{graphics/run1/histogram.tex}`    to include the automatically generated .tex file in my main .tex-file. In the generated file, however, there appears

`\gplbacktext
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics{./histogram}}%
    \gplfronttext`
So I have to change that manually to

`\gplbacktext
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics{./graphics/run1/histogram}}%
    \gplfronttext`
Is there a way to do this more elegantly? I am hoping for an extra command for either the gnuplot script or my main .tex file, so that I don't need to mess with each .tex file of the many graphics that I am planning to include. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
\graphicspath{{./graphics/run1/}}
```

before \begin{document}...

From graphicx package (/ctan/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf, p.13):

> ```
> \graphicspath{<dir-list>}
> ```
>
> This optional declaration may be used to specify a list of directories in which to search for graphics files. The format is the same as for the LaTeX2e primitive `\input@path`. A list of directories, each in a {} group (even if there is only one in the list).
>
> For example:
>   `\graphicspath{{eps/}{tiff/}}`
>   would cause the system to look in the subdirectories `eps` and `tiff`
>   of the current directory. This is unix syntax, on a Mac it would be:
>   `\graphicspath{{:eps:}{:tiff:}}`
>
> Note the differing conventions, an initial : is needed on Macintosh systems to
>   denote the current folder, whereas on unix an initial / would denote the top level 'root' directory.
>
> The default setting of this path is `\input@path` that is: graphics files will be found wherever TeX files are found.

Comment: Sorry. I just update the answer. I think it's more clear now...

Comment: Thanks for the really useful command, never heard of it. Unfortunately, it doesn't quite do what I want. I have identically named files in different subfolders, and for each graphic I need to specify the subfolder that needs to be adressed. So I need a command that does something similar, but locally, only inside the `\begin{figure}`. Or some change in the gnuplot script that leads to the difference in the generated .tex file I posted above.